# .pause() isn't working in Chrome & Firefox, but works fine in Safari

Tags: javascript, video-player

I didn't think I would have an issue with this since Safari was working fine, but it seems that the toggle `videoElement.pause()` isn't firing in Chrome/Firefox. Any ideas of how I can make it cross-browser friendly?

```
 $('a.playBtn.KBAC .pause').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var videoElement = document.getElementById('radioPlayerKbac');
      videoElement.pause();

 });
```

I am using the [viblast player](https://docs.viblast.com/player/video-tag-howto). Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: Works with Jquery 3.3.1. Our bootstrap framework is using 3.4.1. Could that be a problem or maybe where our jquery is being enqueued (footer or header)?

```js
$('a.playBtn.KBAC').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var videoElement = document.getElementById('KBAC');
      videoElement.pause();
 });
```

```css
video {
  height: 280px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ideally this should be in <head> -->  
<script src="//cdn.viblast.com/vb/stable/viblast.js"></script>
<a href="#"class="playBtn KBAC">PAUSE</a>
<!-- body -->
<video id="KBAC" autoplay src="https://58f14b372a413.streamlock.net:444/kbac/kbac.stream_aac/playlist.m3u8?id=1355" data-viblast-key="N8FjNTQ3NDdhZqZhNGI5NWU5ZTI=" controls width="640"></video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging and trying different things, I found this solution:

```
$( "a.playBtn.KBAC .pause" ).click(function(e) {
      var videoElement = document.getElementById('radioPlayerKbac');
          if (!videoElement.paused) {               // Check that video is playing when clicked
              setTimeout(() => {           // V. brief timer to allow default action to occur
                  if (!videoElement.paused) {       // Is it still playing?
                      videoElement.pause();         // Pause it
                  }
              }, 0);
          }
      });
```

This works in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.